# Soma parcial de elementos de um vetor em O(n) ou O(log n)

Tags: algoritmo, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Tenho um vetor A de tamanho n.
Tenho que calcular a soma parcial de cada elemento e escrever na matriz B[i,j].

O pseudo-código mostra uma solução O(n^2);

```
  For i = 1, 2, . . . , n
    For j = i + 1, i + 2, . . . , n
      B[i, j] <- A[i] + A[i+1] + ... +  A[j];
   Endfor
  Endfor
```

Existe uma solução O(n) ou O(log n)? Como seria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da forma que está escrito, o seu algoritmo é O(N<sup>3</sup>). Tem um terceiro loop implícito na parte que você soma os `A[i]`s.

Na forma atual do problema, não tem como ter um algoritmo melhor que O(N<sup>2</sup>). Você tem `N*(N-1)/2` elementos para preencher na matriz `B` então só a parte de escrever a saída já vai ser O(N<sup>2</sup>).

Se você mudar a definição de `B` para ser um vetor unidimensional onde `B[i]` significa a soma de `A[1]` até `A[n]`, ai dá pra fazer em O(N). O truque é reaproveitar os valores já calculados de `B` nas suas contas. (tente fazer isso sem perguntar antes - é um ótimo exercício)

O(log N) não dá porque no mínimo você vai ter que percorrer o vetor `A` uma vez para ler os seus elementos e isso já vai dar O(N).